# NCache Enterprise Edition Installation Issue

Tags: windows-installer, ncache

I have the following problem while trying to setup the **Enterprise NCache** evaluation server on one of my test servers:

***Error 1001.Exception occurred while initializing the installation:
System.ArgumentException: String cannot have a zero length..***

Afterward, the installer tries to launch the NCache Server but cannot and then ask to rollback the progress.

Please let me know if there is a solution available.

Comment: You should direct your question to the vendor that created the installer.

Answer (score 2):

A 1001 error means that an Installer class custom action failed.  The exception indicate some string had no data and an attempt to iterate over it occurred.  It's impossible to know what this code is doing without extracting the custom action and decompiling it.  You are not the original developer of this installer so we can't really help you.

About the only things I can suggest is:

1) Try running the installer from an elevated command prompt.

2) Contact the vendor and tell them that their installer is poorly designed (Installer class custom actions are frowned upon by all windows installer experts) and that they it reflects poorly upon them for your custom evaluation.

Comment: I came across a similar issue when installing NCache.  That was resolved by running from elevated command prompt as well.

Comment: FWIW, I consider these types of failure a form of normalization of deviance.  These types of failures are not accidents.  They are completely anticipated by anyone who has studied installers for more then a few days.